# Iam looking to find the solution to generate the path of a tree.My parent can have more than 2 children

Tags: search, data-structures

I would really love to know if there exist any techique or algorithm to perform this operation.

PS: Backward travelling should not be possible. it should be applicable for n no: of levels

Comment: Stack Overflow is for asking programming-related problems. The question you are asking is too broad. You should expand on your question by explaining what language you are coding in and show any attempts you have made, also what the structure of the data is.

Answer (score 0):

pass a collection to store all node traverse post order and print when it reached at lowest point.

```
void printPathsRecur(Node node, int path[], int pathLen) 
    {
        if (node == null)
            return;

        /* append this node to the path array */
        path[pathLen] = node.data;
        pathLen++;

        /* it's a leaf, so print the path that led to here  */
        if (all node for the parrent is null)
            printArray(path, pathLen);
        else
        {
            for(int i=0;i<node.getChildLenth();i++){
            printPathsRecur(node.child[i], path, pathLen);

        }
    }
```